# Validating input in angular js with numbers and text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

I want my input to be started from exactly 04 and then text can come after but start should be from 04 , i have searched every where but couldn't find any suitable answer.

I have to use ng pattern in angular js.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: show me the code

Answer (score 0):

You should use group in your pattern, surrounded by parenthises. Your regex is
`<... ng-pattern=/^(04).{0,}$/ ...`

`(04)` matches group 04
`.` stands for any character and
`{0,}` stands for 0 or unlimited character.

- If you want to limit characters after "04", just add a max number after `,` sign, like: `{0,4}` for 4 characters.
- If you want to precise minimum number of chars after "04" just change `0` in `{0,}` to your minimum number.
- If you want place number of chars in specific range (i.e. minimum 2 and maximum 5 characters), just use `{2,5}` instead of `{0,}`

Try it yourself:
https://regex101.com/r/0E1QK8/1

Comment: bro need some help here

Answer (score 0):

try

JS

`$scope.pattern = '(04).*';`

HTML

`ng-pattern="pattern"`

check [this working fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/hLigy3xI6UpoPKzHKrKX?p=preview)